# Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on array

Tags: php, html, post, schema, truevault

I'm using the Truevault API and creating a schema for my Vault and eventually the documents that I store in it.

Here is my code:

```
$trueVault = new TrueVault(array(
    "apiKey" => TRUEVAULT_API_KEY,
    "accountId" => TRUEVAULT_ACCOUNT_ID
));

$schemas = $trueVault->schemas(TRUEVAULT_VAULT_ID);
$documents = $trueVault->documents(TRUEVAULT_VAULT_ID);
$blobs = $trueVault->blobs(TRUEVAULT_VAULT_ID); 
var_dump($trueVault->findAllVaults());

$schemas = $schemas->findAll();
var_dump($schemas);

$schemaId = array_search("Referral Form", $schemas);
var_dump($schemaId);
if (!$schemaId) {
    //THIS LINE IS GETTING THE ERROR: 
$schema = $schemas->create(array("name" => "Referral Form", "fields" => array(array("name" => "name", "index" => true, "type" => "string"))));

    $schemaId = $schema["id"];
    echo($schemaId);
}
```

When I run the code on my server, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on array in ...

Comment: and what does your `var_dump($schemas);` tell you? That `$schemas` is an array?

Comment: @MarkBaker It returns nothing. I created a new vault to test out this code so no current schemas exist in it.

Comment: `var_dump()` should always tell you something.... it should at least tell you what datatype a variable is, even if it's an empty array.... e.g. `array(0) { }`

Comment: @VarunIyer You are getting this error because `$schemas` is empty object and therefore has no method named `create`. Ensure that `$trueVault` has been instantiated and not empty as well, then verify that the method `trueVault->schemas()` is _not_ returning an empty object.

Comment: @AhsN @MarkBaker Okay my `$trueVault` and `$schemas` are returning an array. It is instantiated and not empty. What else could be the problem?

Comment: `$schemas` returns `array(0) { } `

Comment: @MarkBaker any suggestions?

Comment: @AhsN any suggestions?

Comment: @VarunIyer Content size of `$schemas` is `(0)` and it contains `{}` empty object. So `$trueVault->schemas()` is not returning anything for some reasons :)

Comment: It looks like `$schemas = $schemas->findAll();` may be setting this variable as an empty array. Try taking this line out and see if the `$schema->create` function works for you.